# Передать значение из контроллера Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Следующим контроллером вношу данные в БД:

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Rastvor;
use Auth;

class RastvorController extends Controller
{


  public function store(Request $request) {
   $contact = new Rastvor;

   $contact->id_otdel = $request->id_otdel;
   $contact->name = $request->name;
   $contact->date = $request->date;
   $contact->method = $request->method;
   $contact->kolvo = $request->kolvo;
   $contact->cons = $request->cons;
   $contact->coef = $request->coef;
   $contact->dategod = $request->dategod;

   $contact->save();

 }


}
```

Форма находится во всплывающем окне и данные в БД заносятся с помощью ajax, поэтому нет return redirect. Из контроллера надо как-то передать в переменные JS данные всей строки (плюс id тоже), которая была внесена в бд.

Ну а вообще конкретно, зачем мне это надо. На странице отрисована табличка, хочу чтобы после внесения новой строки в БД она обновлялась сразу и на страничке. Как сделать добавление новой строки по клику кнопки я разобрался, но вот как получить внесённые значения в БД для внесения их в ячейки таблички не знаю.

Код запроса:

```html
<div class="overlay" id="modal-1">
  <div class="flex-popap">
    <div class="popap">
      <div id="top5">
        <span style="font-size:30px; top:7px!important; position:relative!important; margin-left:25px;cursor: default;">
          Добавить запись
        </span>

        <a class="close_popap"></a>
      </div>

      <div id="banner5" style="width: 650px; ">

        <form id="contactForm">
          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="order">
            <div class="fororder">
              <label for="otdels">{{ __('Отдел') }}</label>
            </div>
          <div class="fororder1">
             <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#nameot').chosen()
          });
            </script>
            <?php
            $sql = DB::select('select id,nameot from otdels');
                echo "<select class='form-control' name = 'nameot' id='nameot' >";
                echo "<option value='' selected disabled></option>";
                  foreach($sql as $row){
              echo "<option value = '$row->id' > $row->nameot </option>";}
                echo "</select>";
                ?>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="order">
        <div class="fororder">
          <label for="rastvor">{{ __('Наименование раствора') }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fororder1">
        <input id="namerast" type="lalka" class="form-control" name="namerast" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>



      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="order">
          <div class="fororder">
            <label for="dateprig">{{ __('Дата приготовления') }}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="fororder1">
            <input id="dateprig" type="date" class="form-control" name="dateprig" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>




        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="order">
          <div class="fororder">
            <label for="method">{{ __('Методика приготовления') }}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="fororder1">
            <input id="method" type="lalka" class="form-control pudge" name="method" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

          <div class="form-group">
        <div class="order">
          <div class="fororder">
            <label for="kolvo">{{ __('Количество приготовленного') }}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="fororder1">
            <input id="kolvo" type="lalka" class="form-control pudge" name="kolvo" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="order">
          <div class="fororder">
            <label for="cons">{{ __('Концентрация раствора') }}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="fororder1">
            <input id="cons" type="lalka" class="form-control pudge" name="cons" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="order">
          <div class="fororder">
            <label for="coef">{{ __('Поправочный коэффициент') }}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="fororder1">
            <input id="coef" type="lalka" class="form-control pudge" name="coef" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="order">
          <div class="fororder">
            <label for="dategodn">{{ __('Срок годности') }}</label>
          </div>
          <div class="fororder1">
            <input id="dategod" type="date" class="form-control pudgeno" name="dategod" autocomplete="name" autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="close_popap btn btn-success" id="submit"></button>
      </div>
      </form>



      <!--
        <div  class="form-group row mb-0" style="position:absolute; left:33.3%; top:453px; color: #FFF !important;">
            <div  class="col-md-6 offset-md-4" >
                <button type="submit" id="buttonenter1" class="buttonenter1">
                    {{ __('Перейти к выбору продукции на испытания') }}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>-->

                        </div>


       <script>

        $('#contactForm').on('submit',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            let id_otdel = $('#nameot').val();
            let name = $('#namerast').val();
            let date = $('#dateprig').val();
            let method = $('#method').val();
            let kolvo = $('#kolvo').val();
            let cons = $('#cons').val();
            let coef = $('#coef').val();
            let dategod = $('#dategod').val();

            $.ajax({
              url: "/contact-form",
              type:"POST",
              data:{
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                id_otdel:id_otdel,
                name:name,
                date:date,
                method:method,
                kolvo:kolvo,
                cons:cons,
                coef:coef,
                dategod:dategod
              },
              success:function(response){

                console.log(response);

              },
             });

            });
          </script>
          <script>
            $('#contactForm').on('submit',function(event){
                  $.ajax({
                      url: "/rastvor",
                      cache: false,
                      success: function(html){

                          $("#banner").html(html);
                      }
                  });
              });
          </script>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: либо json отдайте либо отрендерите строку и хтмл верните

Comment: Ну вот через json вроде что-то есть. Какая там конкретно строчка нужна в контроллере и в самом шаблоне?

Answer (score 0):

Как уже было сказано в комментариях - можно вернуть `json` который далее можно распарсить в `js` и добавить\изменить вашу таблицу.
Пример кода:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $contact = new Rastvor;

  $contact->id_otdel = $request->id_otdel;
  $contact->name = $request->name;
  $contact->date = $request->date;
  $contact->method = $request->method;
  $contact->kolvo = $request->kolvo;
  $contact->cons = $request->cons;
  $contact->coef = $request->coef;
  $contact->dategod = $request->dategod;

  $contact->save();

  return response()->json($contact->toArray());
 }
```

Comment: Ну вот сейчас пытаюсь распарсить, но что-то не получается. out = JSON.parse(contact); вот такое нашёл, но куда конкретно нужно добавить, чтобы посмотреть есть ли там данные. Пробовал через alert(out), но судя по всему пусто.

Comment: @Questionerer Приведите код как вы делаете запрос

Comment: Да просто пытаюсь в один из уже готовых скриптов добавить строчки. let contact = JSON.parse(contact); Но после этой строки скрипт перестаёт обрабатываться.

Comment: Написал вот это out=JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); через алёрт вывелось нормально. А вот если в парсе пишу contact, то скрипт дальше не идёт.

Comment: @Questionerer Погодите, насколько я понял, вы должны выполнить пост запрос на создание записи, при этом передавая значение всех полей, верно?

Comment: Да, пост запрос уже работает, нужно значение полей получить.

Comment: @Questionerer так приведите в своем вопросе код который делает этот пост запрос

Comment: Добавил. Да, могу и отсюда взять значения полей. Но мне нужно и id записи получить, а оно автоматически в бд же создаётся.